# C++ Code Encryption without using password nor key

Tags: c++, visual-c++, encryption

Do you have any idea how to encrypt a C++ code? I do not want to use a password nor key, I just want to save the code on its form, but remove comments, change the variable names and making the code more mysterious and complex to be understood.

Comment: Not going to fool anyone with at least a little bit of skill in understanding code...

Comment: He didn't say that was his goal; he's simply asking what the term for such a tool is.

Comment: @RedRoboHood: and what OTHER goal would there be in doing this? [Yes, I understand that people can ask hypothetical questions, but even when you ask "I have a friend who wonders if..." or "I would like to know if it is possible to...", there is some sort of purpose to why you would like to perform whatever the action is - even if it's just a plot for a novel or film script, if you ask "How would you break into a bank?", the idea isn't to break into a bank without reaching the money, right?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I understand what you're saying, but obviously there must be a valid use case behind obfuscators for people to put so much effort into writing them, correct?

Comment: Yes, the main reason is to removed comments and variables names that explain what to code does. But it's still not going to stop someone from understanding the code if they really want to - just like taking some compiled code and disassembling some code will be understandable if you really put your mind to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is an [obfuscator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29).